# Draw xaxis and yaxis chart with google

Tags: google-visualization

I want to draw chart that can set x between two y for example I want to draw a chart with x=100 and y1=200 , y2=500 just vertical line with good detail which chart can do that for me something like this image

[image]

Which chart I should use I think it should be line chart but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LineChart to do that.  Create a DataTable with columns for `x` and `y` values, then enter your points one row at a time, with linked points adjacent to each other, and empty rows in between (which causes the line to break, so you don't connect to the next vertical pair).  Here's an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X', 'Y'],
        [1, 100], // keep linked points adjacent
        [1, 200],
        [null, null], // insert blank row in between
        [2, 150],
        [2, 275],
        [null, null],
        [3, 75],
        [3, 200],
        [null, null],
        [4, 100],
        [4, 300]
    ]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        pointSize: 5
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/mMy27/